# ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to

Tags: classcastexception

I have an activity in my App that browses Facebook Page albums. It used to work fine but now when I click on it, the App force closes. I haven't made any changes to it at all. Could anyone please help me fix this problem.

The Log message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
$AlbumSelectedListener.onItemSelected(FacebookAlbumDemoActivity.java:181)
```

And Below is the line 181

```
public class AlbumSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener
{
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int pos,long id)
    {
        ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        // Line 181 below
        selectedAlbum=(AlbumItem)spinnerSelectAlbum.getItemAtPosition(pos);
        updateAlbum();
    }
}
```

Where `spinnerSelectAlbum is private Spinner spinnerSelectAlbum;` And `selectedAlbum is private AlbumItem selectedAlbum;`

The AlbumItem class:

```
package com.fb.facebookalbumdemo;

public class AlbumItem{
private String id;
private String name;
private String description;

public AlbumItem(String id,String name,String description){
    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
    this.description=description;
}

public String getId(){
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id){
    this.id=id;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name=name;
}

public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description){
    this.description=description;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    //returning name because that is what will be displayed in the Spinner control
    return(this.name);
}
}
```

After going through all the classes, apparently something is wrong with these two lines in string.xml. After some search on google apparently they have changed the way we retrieve the Albums and Photos from facebook. Is that so? The version of Graph API has changed. Because I haven't changed anything at all in any of the Apps (with graph API) and all of them have stopped working.

```
<string name="facebook_url_albums">graph.facebook.com/myFBid/albums</string>; 
<string name="facebook_url_photos">graph.facebook.com/[ALBUMID]/photos</string>;
```

Comment: according to the error this spinnerSelectAlbum.getItemAtPosition(pos) is returning String and you are trying to cast it to a diff object.

Comment: This exception seems pretty self-explanatory.  Can you check whether line 181 be returning a `String` or not?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It does return a string and cast it to AlbumItem. I have edited my answer and added the code for AlbumItem too. After going through all the classes, apparently something is wrong with these two lines in string.xml. This is not the first App I am using the facebook graph API. All other Apps where I use facebook graph API have stopped working. Not sure why.

<string name="facebook_url_albums">https://graph.facebook.com/myFBid/albums</string>
 <string name="facebook_url_photos">https://graph.facebook.com/[ALBUMID]/photos</string>

Comment: You really should also post your code for the `Spinner` class.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how do you mean by Spinner class code? It's a variable of type Spinner. After some search on google apparently they have changed the way we retrieve the Albums and Photos from facebook. Is that so? The version of Graph API has changed. Because I haven't changed anything at all in any of the Apps and all of them have stopped working.

Comment: Where can we find the source code for the `Spinner` class?